Vulkan program fails to display window
My Vulkan program fails to display a window. The operating system is Arch Linux.
I am not sure what the problem is. However, I can run the sample program from https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan
Code:
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "vulkan", nullptr, nullptr);

    VkInstance instance{};
    VkInstanceCreateInfo info{VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO};

    vkCreateInstance(&info, nullptr, &instance);

    VkSurfaceKHR surfaceKhr;

    glfwCreateWindowSurface(instance, window, nullptr, &surfaceKhr);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    vkDestroySurfaceKHR(instance, surfaceKhr, nullptr);
    vkDestroyInstance(instance, nullptr);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}


I understand that Wayland won’t display a window until something is actually drawn to it. Your code isn’t drawing anything. If your Arch installation is using Wayland, then this could be the problem.
Try booting with a different display manager like Xorg or adding enough code to your program to do a present operation.

Thank you, I solved it, but I have a question. Why does Vulkan need to draw something in the window before it can be displayed when using Wayland, while this is not necessary in X11?

A display server using Wayland does the work of a compositing window manager.  I’m not a Wayland expert, but I think this means the window manager takes a window’s contents and blends it with the contents of all other windows and with the various WM controls.  So if a window is created but not written to yet, it doesn’t make any sense to include it in the overall display composition.

I suppose another way to think of it is that a Wayland display server may not even know about a Wayland client’s window until the client draws something and then gives it to the server, and that doesn’t happen until Vulkan Present.  X11 is just different.

X11 does have the concept of mapping windows which controls their visibility on the screen.  It is likely that GLFW is mapping the window upon creation, making it visible before you draw to it.  There may be an option to create the window without mapping it and then map it later after the first present, making it behave a bit more like it does on Wayland.
